# Cookies in Vue SSR

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering, javascriptservices

I am building an app using .Net Core with VueJs along with JavascriptServices&NodeServices for ServerSideRendering, and Identity as auth mechanism.

Scenario :

I navigate to /details page - having some hidden info because the user is not logged in (so, User.Identity.Name) is null.

I click login, a pop-up shows up, I enter my credentials, and after the AJAX call is made to auth the user, I do a full refresh of the page using location.reload(true).

This works on chrome desktop but on mobile devices it doesn't; on mobile browsers it works if I "fake navigate away" meaning that I go back one page and then come back (so I don't trigger a SSR).

Does anybody have an idea why this doesn't work?